# Nagakami behavoir

Tags: pr.probability, rt.representation-theory

Is the sum of square Nagakami random variables Erlang distributed?

What is the distribution of euclidean norm of complex Nagakami?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Nakagami can be seen as a rescaled chi-distribution, so it's square is a chi-square distribution, which is stable under addition.

Comment: Thanks, I thought the square would be Gamma Distributed. Would the complex Nagakami behave same?